# replaceing innerHTML of div with some html code

Tags: javascript, html

I have  a  div with id xyz.Now i have avariable which has some html code like follows

```
var mycode = "<br>jajaj<b>jjja</b> ";
```

Now i want to replace content of div with this html code by using following

```
document.getElementbyid("xyz").innerHTML = mycode
```

This doenot work.I am not getting why.mycode is dynamicallly created in my code.

if i do simple `document.getElementById("xyz").innerHTML ="some text"`  this works

Comment: try with `getElementById` javascript is key sensitive

Comment: i cant see output of mycode in div

Comment: try to post some more codes. is necessary for problem

Comment: posted a sperate question for it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499221/modifying-text-of-a-div-using-dojo

Answer (score 5):

`getElementById()` [is case sensitive](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/wpuNd/).

Comment: @akshay [It worked for me](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/wpuNd/). Your `mycode` is probably not in the right scope. Can you please post more code? What does `alert(mycode)` popup with just before you attempt to set the `innerHTML` property?

Comment: if i do document.EetElementById("xyz").innerHTML ="some text" it works fine

Comment: @akshay - you need to post the entire code block, not fragments for this to progress.

Comment: I've tried the code: mycode = "<br>jajaj<b>jjja</b> "; document.getElementById("xyz").innerHTML = mycode; and it worked. I used Firebug lite to test it. Could you post all the statements in one place? It could be scope issue.

Comment: am using dojo and there is some variable scoping problem with dojo ,iposted aseperate question for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499221/modifying-text-of-a-div-using-dojo

Answer (score 0):

**You had missed semicolon**

```
 document.getElementbyid("xyz").innerHTML = mycode;
```

Comment: This is very unlikely to be it. An implicit semi-colon will be inserted here unless the fucntion was particularly badly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Have you type your code in this manner?

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="xyz"></div>
<script>
var mycode = "<br>jajaj<b>jjja</b> "; 
document.getElementById("xyz").innerHTML = mycode;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This one worked for me. Please post your sample code so that we can see it.