# modifying text of a div using dojo

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I have a dojo widget.For widget i have  2 files A.js and A.html.Now inside A.html i have something like

```
<div id ="xyz" dojoAttachpoint="xyz"> </div>
```

The above line is one line inside the widget template and its a normal html div

Now in A.js i make a asynchronous call to server.In the callback function of remote method i want modify the text of span xyz.I tryed following 3 ways, but none of them is working.

1) `dojo.byId("xyz").innerHTML = "some text"`
2) `this.xyz.innerHTML ="some text"`

3)

```
 var myWidget = dijit.byId("pack1.abc.widget.widgetname_id");
            myWidget.xyz.innerHTML ="some text"
```

None of the above approach works.

When i use approach 1 in other functions of A.js(non callback functions) it works fine.

Comment: did you ever found solution to this ??

Answer (score 1):

You cannot hardcode the id of a widget in it's template. The id has to identify an instance of a widget-type uniquely, so it has to be given on creation.

You can for example do something like, programmatic in js:

```
var myA = new myWidgets.A({});
myA.startup();
myA.xyz.innerHTML = "some text"
```

or declaratively in html:

```
<div data-dojo-type="myWidgets.A" data-dojo-props="id:'myA'"></div>
```

and js:

```
dijit.byId("myA").xyz.innerHTML = "some text";
```

Comment: I am not hardcoding the id of widget.The html code that i have mentioned resides within the html template of widget.I have edited my original post .

Comment: That still means that you have a html-element-id hardcoded in your widget. If you have several instances of myWidget.A in a page you will have the ID xyz multiple times.

Comment: Also xyz is the id of that one div in you template-html. It is not the id of any instance of myWidget.A.

Comment: I am having only one instcane of widget.I have problem with accessing a span from my js code

Comment: the question is how to access a div/span from the callback async function, this answer is not correct.